# cssでの並び替え

Tags: css

```
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="sentence"></div>
```

上記でPC向けにサイトを作った後、スマホ用にレスポンシブ対応することになったのですが
.imageを.sentenceの下に潜り込ませるにはどうすればいいでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

論理構造が逆になることが許容範囲であれば、以下で可能です。

このソースの肝は、

- PC用ではおそらく画像の縦横が固定なところを利用する
- HTMLの記述をスマホ用にする
- CSSをPC用に記述（Media Queryなどを用いる）

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.images {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.sentence {
  padding-top: 150px; /* 画像の高さ */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sentence">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="images"><img src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

もう一つの解。
画像の縦横比が決まっているのであれば、以下。

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 75%; /* 画像の比率 縦/横 */
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="images"><img src="https://placehold.jp/400x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="sentence">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi error quae autem, quod ad eveniet hic tempora tenetur nemo animi natus magnam maxime in rerum, modi, rem assumenda ea exercitationem?</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

単純に、表示するレイアウトの話でしょうか。

全体がみえないのでなんとも言えませんが
CSSで解決するのは難しい、または推奨出来ないかなと思います。
シンプルに要素を入れ替えてしまいたいのであれば
jQueryなりで操作をするのが良いと思います。

CSSで解決するには、下記のような記述が必要になります。
動的に高さが変動する場合は難しいですし
何よりも、おすすめできる書き方ではありません。
jQueryのコードもコメントアウトし記述しておきましたので
こちらで解決するのが望ましいかと思います。
他の要素も有る場合は`insertAfter`等も活用してみてください。

```js
//$('.image').appendTo('.container');
```

```css
.image{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
  background:red;
  
  /* 以下位置調整 */
  position:relative;
  top: 110px;
  }

.sentence{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
  background:blue;
  
  /* 以下位置調整 */
  position:relative;
  top: -110px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">上の要素</div>
    <div class="sentence">下の要素</div>
</div>
```